# Browsing to parent directory from symlinks in Ubuntu

Tags: shortcuts, symbolic-link

When you make a link to a folder in Ubuntu, one cannot navigate to the directory above that link. Is there any way to get around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're browsing in a shell, you could use

```
cd "$(pwd -P)" ; cd ..
```

`-P` means the physical (real) directory to which the current one is a link

Comment: I mean browsing in gui.